# How to unserialize database value

Tags: php, serialization, continuous-integration

I have set dep_id in session which would have to compare in database dep_id value in session dep_id value is eg: 22 and in database dep_id value is in serialize format. 
i have a following code:

```
public function notice_to_employee($dep_id, $published=null){
  $select = array('id','title', 'slug', 'content', 'ent_date', 'exp_date', 'published', 'dep_id');

  $result = $this->db->select($select)
                    ->where('published',1)
                    ->where_in('dep_id', $dep_id)
                    ->get('notice_board')
                    ->result();


  if($result){
    return $result;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Note: Where_in condition is not working.
Thank you

Comment: If you have the serialized version of `dep_id` in Database, don't you need `->where_in('dep_id', serialize($dep_id))` to fetch it up? - Basically without un-serializing DB value, you can serialize id and check it against DB.

Comment: no it doesnot work , SELECT `id`, `title`, `slug`, `content`, `ent_date`, `exp_date`, `published`, `dep_id` FROM `default_notice_board` WHERE `published` = 1 AND `dep_id` IN ('s:2:\"22\";')-- print_r , is empty Array ( )

Comment: How you do the serialized version to DB? do you have the code for that?

Comment: in controller i simply insert dep_id in  this way , $data['dep_id']   = serialize($this->input->post('dep_id'));

Comment: What is the reason for you to serialize this ID? just to understand your logic. Is it always a `INT`?

Comment: in database my data is a:2:{i:0;s:2:"14";i:1;s:2:"22";} now my dep_id is 22 so i want to compare that 22 in  database value ... if there is 22 in database data print  if not do noting

Comment: Basically your DB value is an serialized array, not a string value. actually what you have in DB is Array(0 => "14", 1 => "22"). Is this what you have saved in the DB? I doubt that, what you are saving in this field is not right. I think first you need to figure out what is 22 and 14. Then you should decide what is the need of serializing this ID.

Comment: What is the framework you are using?